# JavaFx TableView (TV) with ObservableList (OL): How to edit the TV and update the OL automatically

Tags: javafx, tableview, observablelist

I am using an ObservableList which is attached to a TableView. Now first of all I want to make the TableView editable and then when specific fields get edited, I want to update the corresponding object in the ObservableList. But somehow I struggle with getting the updated value from the TableView. And if I use

`tv_column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());`

then I get the error:

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

My Cell Value Factory:

`tv_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SaleItem,Double>("quantity"));`

Models:

```
public interface SaleItem {
    void setProductName(String productName);
    void setPrice(double price);
    double getPrice();
    double getTotalPrice();
    void setTotalPrice();
    String getProductCode();
    String getProductCodeDescription();
    String getDescription();
    String getProductName();
}

public abstract class NonFuel implements SaleItem {
    public SimpleIntegerProperty quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleDoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
    public SimpleStringProperty productName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    SimpleDoubleProperty totalPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
    // getter and setter
}

public class Drinks extends NonFuel {
    public Drinks() {
        setProductName("Coffee");
        setPrice(2.20);
        setQuantity(1);
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

Can somebody help getting the new Value from the TV or updating the OL behind it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your model class and cell value factory

Comment: Thanks @James_D. Your Input really helped me where to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that there were two problems:

1. The double or integer Value from my Model needed to be converted to and from string. I can configure this directly in the column:

   ```
   tv_column.setCellFactory(
       TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(
           new StringConverter<Double>() {
               @Override
               public String toString(Double object) {
                   return Double.toString(object);
               }

               @Override
               public Double fromString(String string) {
                   return Double.valueOf(string);
               }
           }
       )
   );
   ```
2. On the other hand I had to get the event of editing the cell and give the new value to the Item of the ObservableList. Then I had to update the item and refresh the TableView:

   ```
   tv_column.setOnEditCommit(
       new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SaleItem, Double>>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SaleItem, Double> event) {
               SaleItem saleItem =  event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow());
               saleItem.setQuantity(event.getNewValue());
               saleItem.updatePrice();
               tv.refresh();
           }
       }
   );
   ```

Comment: dont use table.refresh EVER - it's emergency api if there can't be any notification mechanism (which isn't the case in your context) Instead, use an observableList with extrator to make the list fire an update event on change to properties in other columns